# Customize boot2docker.iso to use wireless devices on containers (Docker-toolbox)

Tags: docker, kernel, dockerfile, wireless, boot2docker

I already have a Docker container which is fully working on Linux hosts. Now I want it working on Windows and Mac OS X. This container is using USB wireless interfaces. In Linux, it is as simple as using `--net=host` on the Docker run command and that's all. With that, I can see the wireless interfaces inside the container and putting `--privileged` I can change them to monitor mode. Now let's try in Windows/Mac...

My investigations brought me to choose Docker-toolbox for Windows/Mac. It seems is not possible to map USB devices with standard Docker on this host OS. Now, using a VirtualBox "default" machine, I installed the VirtualBox extension pack and created the filters to attach USB devices into containers. Now I can see (at last!!!) USB devices into containers using the `lsusb` command which are great news... but unfortunately I can't see them yet as wireless interfaces doing `iwconfig`.

I guess it is because the default boot2docker machine doesn't have drivers for this. So, my investigations brought me again into the next step...

I'm trying to create a custom boot2docker.iso with wireless drivers. I saw in Dockerfile at the official [boot2docker GitHub page](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker) a command what I think is "screwing up" my plans... the command is `rm -rf ./*/kernel/net/wireless/*`.

It seems it remove them intentionally. I tried to remove that line and build the image generating a new ISO image. To create a custom boot2docker iso is as simple as download (clone) the repo and having Docker installed then execute this `docker build -t boot2docker . && docker run --rm boot2docker > boot2docker.iso`. It will generate a new iso file.

Then I tried on both systems (Windows and mac) recreating the VirtualBox default machine based on this new ISO image (overwritting the default iso, deleting the machine and creating it again), but it was unsuccessfully. I can't see the wireless interfaces as "wlanx" inside the container.

Which is the procedure to create a boot2docker ISO image file with wireless drivers support? Am I missing something? Does anybody have already an ISO image I can use?

**EDIT**
I modified a lot of things on Dockerfile. There is a `kernel_config` file with all the kernel options. Obviously the target is to generate a iso with all kernel options set up in order to support wireless operations... so I put all the wireless drivers enabled (not as modules, I mean as included to be detected automatically), as much as I can (atheros, realtek, ralink, intel, etc)... all options enabled an kernel. I enabled too "CONFIG_USB_MON=y" flag to be able to use monitor mode.

In addition of all the kernel options which I'm investigating and learning... of course the drivers must be added too to the iso. For that, there is another part of Dockerfile I'm modifying. It uses tinycore and all available packages are here: http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/7.x/x86_64/tcz/ and I installed all wireless related packages including firmware packages which are drivers in the end.

I'm in the right direction because Now I can see wireless interfaces inside the container... even I put one of them (a Ralink Alfa) in monitor mode but unfortunately after scanning using airodump inside the container it shows no packets. I'm missing something... :/

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT2** I forked [boot2docker repository](https://github.com/OscarAkaElvis/boot2docker). I pushed my changes on Dockerfile and kernel_config files. If anybody want to try something is welcome... as I said, at this point, we are able to see wireless interfaces inside container and to put them on monitor mode... but no packets captured. Something related to driver is wrong, I guess kernel stuff is ok now... I'll keep trying with different chipsets.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I may need to do a little more research to fully grasp your question here. But from my understanding you're essentially trying to create a container network that is bound to a custom network interface (your USB wireless interface)? If so, we have documentation on how to create a container network that's bound to a specific network interface [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-networking#bind-a-network-to-a-specific-network-interface). Have you tried that approach? Basically you should be able to use the option, `-o com.docker.network.windowsshim.interface=<Interface>` with the `docker network create` command to specify which host interface your new network should use. You can then attach your containers to the network that is bound to the correct interface, then you should have connectivity.

Comment: I think what you propose if to use docker with hyper-v. Am I wrong? What I'm trying to do is with Docker-toolbox using the Virtualbox vm because in that way it will work for OSX environment too. Anyway thanks for your answer, is very interesting and of course I'll check that too.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had time to try it, so take this with a grain of salt, but [this guide](http://gw.tnode.com/docker/docker-machine-with-usb-support-on-windows-macos/) recommends Docker Machine and that makes sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for you link. I'm pretty close to achieve it. I'm modifying Dockerfile and kernel_options file and compiling it in an infinite loop of try and error... but I'm pretty close!! I can see now the wlan0 adapter inside the container... now I'm fighting with it to put it on monitor mode... if finally I achieve it I'll put here an entire explanation about how to do it.

Comment: Haha amazing :) Please do keep me posted!

Comment: Ohh my god... I can put the card in monitor but on scanning no packets are shown... I am missing something!!! ... pretty pretty close...

Comment: The anticipation is killing me haha

Comment: I updated the question with my researchs and results.

Comment: I edited with more data. Now you can see my boot2docker forked repo to see what modifications I did on Dockerfile and kernel_config.

Comment: Stepping back one second, why are you choosing Docker-toolbox rather than Docker for Windows?  I'm worried you'll get stuck on a [slower moving branch](https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/) even if you do manage to get it working

Comment: For two reasons. First one is if I finally make it work, it will work for win and for mac too because docker-toolbox is exactly the same for both systems (based on virtualbox host machine). The second reason is I don't have idea about how to modify the host for other Docker host. Can the kernel options be modified? Can I add drivers? If yes, how? a link or guide could be helpful.

Comment: If you really want it to work on Windows and Mac my guess is toolbox is your best bet, like you said.  What do you mean by "modify the host for other Docker host"?

Comment: I mean I don't kno how to manipulate and change the machine that will be the host for docker containers on a system different than docker-toolbox. I know very well on docker-toolbox there is a virtual machine which is created based on an iso file. If I install the other docker instead of docker toolbox... I guess will be another vm somewhere (I don't know where) and I don't know how to manipulate or change it. Because in the end is what I need... to modify the machine that will be the host for docker containers trying to add to it kernel options an drivers to support wireless interfaces.